# Truncation of labels in material design

Tags: css, angular-material, material-design

In material forms, how to avoid truncation of labels in input containers?
how can we make longer labels fully visible? Select options also have the same issue.

Comment: Can you post the code you have tried so far, please?

Comment: this is a common issue in angular material input component i think

Answer (score 0):

Just apply some css to see if it helps:

```
.mat-select-value,
.mat-form-field-label {
  overflow: initial;
  text-overflow: initial;
}
```

Comment: .mat-select-value,
.mat-form-field-label {
    overflow: initial;
    text-overflow: initial;
    white-space: inherit;
}

I tried this but is not a perfect solution because longer label comes to the next line which is over lap with the value.

.mat-input-element{
  margin-top:10px;
}

we can move the input element little bit down but that space will take everywhere ..

Any other solution is there for this issue?

Comment: I guess you could to create a custom form field control with your own label. https://material.angular.io/guide/creating-a-custom-form-field-control